# AZURE SQL Server and Office 365 Excel Authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, powerquery

We've been using Power Query within Excel 2013 to access an Azure SQL Server (which isn't ours but we have access to - Vendors application). Not sure at what point there was a change and what the change might have been (and apparently our vendor is clueless as well) but now every time I try to create a new workbook and use Power Query I can't seem to pass authentication to connect to the server.

Oddly, all of my legacy workbooks continue to work and my connection to the server works fine when connecting through Management Studio. Is there some sort of special permission on SQL Server (or somewhere else in the Azure environment) that requires specific configuration to allow connections from Power Query? I don't understand why management studio and legacy queries work fine but I can't create new connections.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the navigation flow as follows in Excel 2013: Get Data > From Database > From SQL Server Database? With Office 365, is the navigation: Get Data > From Azure > From Azure SQL Database? With your Office 365 Excel subscription, are you using the desktop instance or the Office 365 hosted instance (from a browser session)? There is likely a firewall issue preventing the IP Address from connecting to the database, as you are likely not connecting from an IP Address allowed to connect per the allow list.

Comment: Thank you for the response the Query is in Excel/Power Query and it's trying to Pull from a remote Azure SQL Server... I don't think it's a firewall issue, I believe it is an authentication or permissions error... I do get a firewall related message if I use the workbook query from home but I get the authentication error from work (because they've whitelisted my work IP address). Please let me know if you have any more ideas, it's definitely appreciated.